# how to set ratingbar and text relative to another text in android

Tags: android

ho[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20.5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="172dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="31.5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Mike Johnson" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/genre"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title"
            android:text="Mike Johnson" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/genre1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/genre"
            android:text="Mike Johnson"

            />


    </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativelayout"
        android:layout_marginTop="25.5px">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20.5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="175.09px"
            android:layout_marginTop="7px"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Feb 26,2016" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ptitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/date"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20.5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="150px"
            android:text="GREAT SOCKS TO BUY"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pdesc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ptitle"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20.5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20px"
            android:layout_marginTop="14px"
            android:text="asdsad  asdasda saddfasdsad asdasdsadsa asdsadsadsar asdfdsfdsrf asddsfdsafds adssargfavcx " />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bottomline"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/pdesc"
            android:layout_marginBottom="11px"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20.5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20px"
            android:text="Yes i would like sklsadsa " />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relativelayout">

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/rateM"
            style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:indeterminate="false"
            android:isIndicator="true"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:stepSize="1.0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/arrow"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
             android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/rateM"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="4" />


    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

i want set rating bar just right of text view which coming correct but theere another text where 4 is ovelaping on rating bar i want keep that text  right of rating bar please suggest me how to implment this.i am bignner.

Comment: consider using `LinearLayout` in place of inner `RelativeLayouts` with different orientation.

Answer (score 0):

remove following line from textView 4

```
 android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/rateM"
```

and add this to rating bar

```
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/arrow"
```

remove following line from rating bar

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

and place textView 4 above rating bar view

Comment: i have changed but sill same  and what is arrow @Ali Ahsan